# scroll a-sky vertically on mobile

Tags: aframe

I try to make use of `a-sky` for displaying a vr photo. It works great on a PC. On mobile I cannot scroll vertically (horizontal scroll works fine with one finger). How can I make vertical scroll work?

The code is as simple as it gets:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-sky src="ciasto.jpg" color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried switching to the computer version of the page, tried different browsers (Opera, Chrome). All behave the same.

I was also analyzing how the `a-sky` example at [glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/aframe-adding-a-sky?path=index.html) works. It's quite amazing. When using preview inside a frame, it acts as in my example. But when entering a new window, the image shakes as crazy, because it tries to make use of gyro, so it's rather not a way to go.

Answer (score 2):

It is designed to only have horizontal scroll on mobile devices. You can check out how look-controls implemented here https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/components/look-controls.js#L351C9-L351C9

As you can see, move action only updates yawObject. You can duplicate this component locally and create a version that also updates pitchObject. Then you need to give new look-controls component to camera and disable the original one.

Updated onTouchMove function should look like this:

```js
onTouchMove: function(evt) {
  var direction;
  var canvas = this.el.sceneEl.canvas;
  var deltaY;
  var deltaX;
  var yawObject = this.yawObject;

  if (!this.touchStarted || !this.data.touchEnabled) {
    return;
  }

  deltaX = 2 * Math.PI * (evt.touches[0].pageY - this.touchStart.y) / canvas.clientHeight;
  deltaY = 2 * Math.PI * (evt.touches[0].pageX - this.touchStart.x) / canvas.clientWidth;

  direction = this.data.reverseTouchDrag ? 1 : -1;
  pitchObject.rotation.x -= deltaX * 0.5 * direction;
  yawObject.rotation.y -= deltaY * 0.5 * direction;

  this.touchStart = {
    x: evt.touches[0].pageX,
    y: evt.touches[0].pageY
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the perfect explanation. The touchMove implementation seems to be unfinished. I'll try to find a way to file this as a bug.

Comment: There is an already closed bug report: [5097](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/5097)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your heading section you forgot to add in the default mobile resize for html.

Here is the default header structure:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```

Comment: I added those lines in the `head` section. That doesn't help.

There is also another difference between PC and mobile view. Only on PC there is a four arrows icon to "Enter VR mode..."